# Model property name differs with CSV dataset column name

Tags: ml.net

I am writing a machine learning program in C# using ML.NET. The dataset is a CSV file with header row. The model input class looks similar to following:

```
public class ModelInput
{
    [LoadColumn(0), ColumnName("Step")]
    public float RecordId;

    [LoadColumn(1), ColumnName("Type")]
    public string? Type;
}
```

The preferred way to refer to the `Type` CSV column would be `nameof(ModelInput.Type)`. Is there a similar convenient way to refer to the `Step` CSV column besides probing the `ModelInput.RecordId` property via reflection? As it is the CSV column names which are referred in data view, pipelines etc.

I would prefer not to make the model property names same as the CSV column name.

Also I can see that when there is no header row the DataView schema takes the field names as the model class properties itself.